# Durandal 2.0 Router - how to specify Id?

Tags: durandal

I have this working in Durandal 1.2:

[Durandal Routing: Mapping a route with an id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16765756/durandal-routing-mapping-a-route-with-an-id)

```
{ 
url: 'test',
hash: '#/test',
moduleId: 'viewmodels/folder',
name: 'Specific Folder',
visible: false,
settings: {
    id: 2
}
}
```

However it appears that the router no longer supports settings specification: http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Conversion-Guide/

How can this be achieved in 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with the new router, unfortunately.

However, if your goal is simply to get some value into the `activate` method of a viewmodel during navigation (which is all `settings` did), you do not need the router to do that. I am assuming that the value isn't actually hard coded, but determined by something. Just make this "something* available to the viewmodel, and call it inside of the `activate` method.

As long as you get where you're going, right?